# Python Regex: Finding files without a certain extension

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to figure out the regular expression to use in order to search a directory and return the number of files in the directory that do not have a certain prefix 'abc_'.  E.g, in a directory with files def_notes.txt, abc_notes.txt, ghi_notes.txt, the function would recognize that there are two files without the 'abc_' prefix and return 2.

To get to the point, I'm having trouble writing a regular expression to represent this.  I've tried re.compile('^(.(?!(abc_)))*$') which I found [here](http://www.lisnichenko.com/articles/javapython-inverse-regex.html).  However, this doesn't seem to work.  Leaving the first dot inside the parenthesis actually matches a file 'abc_notes.txt'.  If I remove that dot, it won't match 'abc_notes.txt', but it also doesn't match 'def_notes.txt'.

Edit: To clarify, I'll use glob or the os packages to do the work once I figure out the expression.  I'm just using re.compile and search in the python shell to figure out the regex.

Comment: I wouldn't use a regex for that.  Just `os.walk` and pure python

Comment: You can write a regex to test if a single file name matches or doesn't match your pattern, but regexes aren't very good at counting things. You'll need to iterate over your files and test each one, then count them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This code prints out how many files in the current directory don't start with the letter `z`:

```
import glob, re

print len( [path for path in glob.glob('*')
            if not path.startswith('z')
            ]
           )
```

The following code uses a regular expression.  It matches for the letter 'z' at the beginning of the string -- then reverses the match with the `(?!...)` syntax.

```
pat = re.compile('^(?!z)')
print len( filter(None, map(pat.match, glob.glob('*'))) )
```